# Issues Resolving Overdraw in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have massive overdraw issues in my app, worst part is its the entire window even my toolbar is affected, I have trimmed down my layouts to the lowest possible hierarchy I can come up with but to no avail, here is a screenshot of my app[image]

I have an activity which am inflating in it a fragment with a recyclerview
Here is my recyclerview adapter layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/parentHolder"
android:background="@null"
android:layout_height="80dp">





            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/receiptImage"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
               />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="2"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/merchantName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize = "16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="Merchant Name"
                   />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/receiptCategory"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize = "13sp"
                    android:text="Food"

                   />

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:id="@+id/date"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize = "12sp"
                    android:text="12 April, 2016"
                  />



            </LinearLayout>




            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">




                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/price"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:textColor="@color/accent"
                    android:textStyle="italic|bold"
                    android:text="$ 12.900"
                    android:textSize = "16sp"
                    />


                <com.rey.material.widget.CheckBox
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
```

Fragment Layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/receipts_recycler_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

My Activity layout:

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@null"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ManagerActivity">



    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Total Expenses"
                android:textColor = "@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0.0"
                android:textColor = "@color/white"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small"
                android:id="@+id/total_expenses" />


            </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">

    </FrameLayout>





  </LinearLayout >
```

And finally here is my theme I have a feeling it has something to do with this but sadly I am not very familiar with themes maybe someone here can point out the issue

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <!-- MaterialDrawer specific values -->
    <item name="material_drawer_background">@color/material_drawer_dark_background</item>
    <item name="material_drawer_primary_text">@color/material_drawer_dark_primary_text</item>
    <item name="material_drawer_secondary_text">@color/material_drawer_dark_secondary_text
    </item>
    <item name="material_drawer_hint_text">@color/material_drawer_dark_hint_text</item>
    <item name="material_drawer_divider">@color/material_drawer_dark_divider</item>
    <item name="material_drawer_selected">@color/material_drawer_dark_selected</item>
    <item name="material_drawer_selected_text">@color/royal_blue</item>
    <item name="material_drawer_header_selection_text">
        @color/material_drawer_dark_primary_text
    </item>

    <!-- CAB :D -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set @null on layout background attribute,it will not draw its background.So I also wonder about why overdraw issues are serious.

You can remove the background of theme by adding this code in your theme file:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
```

It do optimization on overdraw.According to this:[enter link description here](http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2009/03/window-backgrounds-ui-speed.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have finally fix the overdraw and its perfect, I had to make a few changes to my adapter, from an expandable adapter to a normal adapter and other additional corrects, but even after that my app was still performing poorly, then I looked at my adapter again and noticed for every adapter I was creating a `typeface` object and assigning a new `font` to my adapter, this was taking a reasonable amount of time and `CPU` strength hence the lags so I just removed the `typeface` and my app was back to the top, here is my current `GPU` drawings of my app[image]